# VB.Net Getting the sum of 3 columns below

Tags: vb.net

[image]

Can't seem to find how to get the sum of three columns in a datagrid.

```
Public Class form1
Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
Dim Command As MySqlCommand
Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim bSource As New BindingSource
Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
            "Server= localhost ;User Id = root ;password= ; database=smd"

Dim table As New DataTable()
        Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Emp_Name as 'Employee Name', section as 'Section', SL, MDL, VL, Total  from recap", MysqlConn)
        adapter.Fill(table)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = table
```

Comment: You should paste your code, so we can help you. I guess you must sum the three columns in your ViewModel, but I cannot know if you have a ViewModel if you do not show your actual code. Thank you

Comment: sorry about that how can i do that? im really new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the sum in the SELECT clause:

```
Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Emp_Name as 'Employee Name', section as 'Section', SL, MDL, VL, SL+MDL+VL as Total  from recap", MysqlConn)
```

What we have done is to get the sum from the server.

Comment: May I Ask how? I'm really new

Comment: Take a look at the Total in my code: SL+MDL+VL as Total. What we do is to tell the server to sum the three columns. Try it, please, and tell me if this is what you are looking for, please.

Comment: sorry i did not notice that you added a code. Thank you! it works now perfectly. can't seem find answers from searching at google :) Thanks Alot

Comment: If so, mark my answer as the good one, please :) Very glad to help you